# Java - Swing UI separate socket logic

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, user-interface

I become desperate, I develop a simple multi-user chat in Java based on the client-server principle. I already wrote a basic multi-threaded server application and it works great. My problem is the client on the basis of the Swing GUI Toolkit. A basic UI with a runtime loop for receiving messages in the background. My problem is that I want to separate the socket logic from the UI, this means that in the best case I've two different classes one for the socket runtime loop and another to manage the UI. Because of the problem, that the runtime loop must notify/add messages to the UI, they depend on each other.

- `MessengerView` is my main class which contains the swing ui and all depended components. At the moment this class contains also the socket logic, but I want to extract them to an external class.
- `ClientRuntime` the class which should hold the socket logic...

My question is, how could I separate them and how could I connect them? For example I tried swing-like events with registering of methods like this:

```
addListener(MessageArrivedListener listener);
emitMessageArrivedEvent(String message);
```

The problem is, that it is very confusing if the count of events raises! As already said my second options is to hold socket logic and ui design in one class, but I think it's a bad idea because it makes it very hard to write unit tests for it or to find bugs...

In my time with C++ I used sometimes friend-classes for this issue, because this makes it possible to access class members of other classes! But this solution is often also very confusing and I found no such option for Java.

So are there any other possibilities to hold the connection between the swing widgets and the socket logic, without storing them in the same class (file)?

Comment: What do you mean by `The problem is, that it is very confusing if the count of events raises!`. Also have you looked into implementing your own listener? This way you can have your socket logic running in a separate thread somewhere else and just fine events whenever you want to notify your UI about a change.

Comment: @Aris Yea of coursd I wrote my own listener but as I already said I had to write a lot of them... For me it seems to be very confusing becaus I didn't have the overview who does what becaus I don't have only one swing view, there is also a ui form for sign in for example and it is also connected via events to the socket holding class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> they depend on each other

Well, they don't really.  The "socket" layer only cares about been started, running, posting some messages and stopping.

How all that actually get done/handled it doesn't care about, it just "starts" when told, processes input/output messages, posts notifications and "stops" when asked to.

This is basically an observer pattern, or if you prefer, a producer/consumer pattern.

So the socket layer needs to define a "protocol" of behaviour or contract that it's willing to work with. Part of that contract will be "how" it generates notifications about new messages, either via an observer or perhaps through a blocking/readonly queue - that's up to you to decide.

As for the UI, it's a little more complicated, as Swing is single threaded, so you should not block the UI with long running or blocking operations.  This is where something like a `SwingWorker` would come in handy.

It basically acts a broker between the UI and the mechanism made available by the socket layer to receive messages.  Messages come from the socket layer into the `SwingWorker`, the `SwingWorker` then `publish`es them onto the UI's event thread which can then be safely updated onto the UI

Maybe start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

> My question is, how could I separate them and how could I connect them? For example I tried swing-like events with registering of methods like this:
>   The problem is, that it is very confusing if the count of events raises!

I don't think so (IMHO).  What you want to do is focus on the "class" of events.  For example, from the above, you have "life cycle" events and you have "message" events.  I'd start by breaking those down into two separate interfaces, as those interested in "message" events probably aren't that interested in "life cycle" events, this way you can compartmentalise the observers.

The important concept you want to try and get your head around is the proper use of `interfaces to define "contracts", this becomes the "public" view of the implementations, allowing you devise different implementations for different purposes as you ideas change and grow.  This decouples the code and allows you to change one portion without adversely affecting other parts of the API

Answer (score 1):

`how could I separate them and how could I connect them?`

Connect them with `BlockingQueue` - this the first choice when choosing ways to connect threads.

`ClientRuntime` class must start 2 threads: one takes requests from the blocking queue and sends them to the server, and the second constantly reads the messages from the server through the socket and sends them to the UI thread. The UI thread has already input blocking queue for messages: it is accessed by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);`. The `ClientRuntime` class does not access UI queue directly: it calls a method from `MessengerView` and passes what it received from the socket, a binary array or json string, and that UI method converts it to some `Runnable` which actually updates the UI.